# Cloudfront exception "The If-Match version is missing or not valid for the resource." when updating distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk-js

When updating a Cloudfront distribution using the AWS Node SDK I get the following exception:

```
  message:
   'The If-Match version is missing or not valid for the resource.',
  code: 'InvalidIfMatchVersion',
  time: 2020-08-23T19:37:22.291Z,
  requestId: '43a7707f-7177-4396-8013-4a704b7b11ea',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 57.05741843025996 }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error occurs because you need to first get the current distribution config with `cloudfront.getDistributionConfig` and then copy the `ETag` and `DistributionConfig` fields into your `cloudfront.updateDistribution` call. You modify the `DistributionConfig` as needed to achieve the actual config update you're trying to do.

The docs do a poor job of explaining this (the instructions are for the REST API instead of the actual SDK you're using).

The following is an example of updating a Cloudfront distribution to be disabled by pulling the latest distribution config, modifying it, and then performing an update with it:

```js
async function disable_cloudfront_distribution(dist_id) {
    // We need to pull the previous distribution config to update it.
    const previous_distribution_config = await cloudfront.getDistributionConfig({
        Id: dist_id
    }).promise();
    const e_tag = previous_distribution_config.ETag;

    // Update config to be disabled
    previous_distribution_config.DistributionConfig.Enabled = false;

    // Create update distribution request with distribution ID
    // and the copied config along with the returned etag for ifmatch.
    const params = {
        Id: dist_id,
        DistributionConfig: previous_distribution_config.DistributionConfig,
        IfMatch: e_tag
    };

    return cloudfront.updateDistribution(params).promise();
}
```

Comment: I just ran into this and according to the documentation that `IfMatch` should be optional:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cloudfront/interfaces/updatedistributioncommandinput.html#ifmatch  ?!? ... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯