# AWS Exception "The If-Match version is missing or not valid for the resource" when updating using web interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

When updating my AWS Cloudfront distribution using the AWS web interface, I get the following error: "The If-Match version is missing or not valid for the resource.".

I cannot disable, delete, update or do any actions on the distribution to my knowledge.

[image]

There's similar [questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551534/cloudfront-exception-the-if-match-version-is-missing-or-not-valid-for-the-resou), but they deal with the AWS console.

Have I done something, or have AWS miss-used their own API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was caused by the ClearURLs plugin I had installed in Chrome.

https://repost.aws/questions/QUdbuTO7zDRkWBHhQ6K7tDqA/cant-edit-the-if-match-version-is-missing-or-not-valid-for-the-resource

Comment: I had the same plugin for Firefox, same error. Running in a Private tab was the easiest way to disable all plugins and remove the error.